# align span size as per content

Tags: html, css

I've below HTML and CSS

here the span content is overlapping the para content, is there a way, where i can get this data not overlapping the para content, it is ok even if the san content is displayed in two lines.

```css
.chapter {
    margin-left: 5.0em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
.para {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-top: 0.85em;
}
.para span.phrase {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-left: -4.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2.8em;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="para">
<span class="phrase">8.04</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">25.101-25.102</span>
The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">8AA.01</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can specify a width for it and it will go on 2 rows,there are other ways but re-think your code it's a little stiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a width for phrase and break the word to next line using `word-break: break-all`

```css
.chapter {
    margin-left: 5.0em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
.para {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-top: 0.85em;
}
.para span.phrase {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-left: -4.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2.8em;
    position:absolute;
    width: 70px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="para">
<span class="phrase">8.04</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">25.101-25.102</span>
The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">8AA.01</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a width for the `phrase` class will fix it:

```css
.chapter {
    margin-left: 5.0em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
.para {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-top: 0.85em;
}
.para span.phrase {
    width: 4.75em; /* <-- Here */
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-left: -4.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2.8em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="para">
<span class="phrase">8.04</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">25.101-25.102</span>
The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">8AA.01</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
</div>
```